# How to get access right THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION for thread handle in Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, initialization

I want to use GetExitCodeThread(). The MSDN documentation says, 
"The handle must have the THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION or THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right."
I use _beginthreadex() to create my thread.
When I call this API, how should I set THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION flag? Should it be part of initFlag? The documentation does not say how exactly this flag has to be set.

Comment: You have the source, have a look in vc/crt/src.  It uses CreateThread(), MSDN documents that the thread handle has THREAD_ALL_ACCESS rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handle returned by `_beginthreadex` already has more than enough access to the thread to query limited information. After all, it has permission to terminate the thread, which is far more than just querying limited information.

Comment: Chen and Hans, Thanks to both the answers.